# Why does iTunes→IOS sync copied items not correspond to what has actually changed?

Tags: ios, itunes, data-synchronization

Recently, I edited an MP3 file that was in iTunes.  Cut almost sixty seconds off the end of it, and changed some tags.  iTunes did not recognize the change in duration until I exited and relaunched.  However, after that, in two or three syncs, the duration on the iPad did not change, and listening showed that the noise at the end was still there.  The only way I found to fix it was to tell iTunes to NOT sync that song, sync, and then sync again with the song checked.

Conversely, every time I sync iPhone or iPad, at least two or three dozen songs that have never been changed are re-copied.  These are not purchased songs, but imported from CD.

What might be causing this discrepancy?  It's not permissions—I periodically `chmod -R a+w ~\Music\iTunes` because a couple of times long ago a different error was caused by some unknown action causing a permissions error in the library.

MacOS, iTunes, and IOS are all the latest versions, and this has been happening over several versions of each.

UPDATE: 3½ years later, it is worse.  Audio and embedded lyrics were **completely** replaced in seven MP3 files, one album.  Some of the metadata also changed.  (Track and album names kept the same but an ID3 moment was changed.)  After a sync, six of the tracks were updated; one was still the old version.  A couple more minor changes to audio and lyrics, `touch` to change the modification date, and re-sync.  Still the old version on the iPad (and verified the news is in the laptop library).

Changed sync setting "all songs" to only selected and removed that album from the selections.  Resync, change back to "all songs," and resync.  Old version still there!

With Music app not running, used Finder to move the file to the Desktop.  Launched Music, and deleted the track.  Re-sync, re-import the track, re-sync.  Old version still there.

Finally, opened the file in Amadeus Pro, and a copy of the lyrics in TextEdit.  Minor change to lyrics, save file.  Major changes to audio, save file.  Use [eyeD3](https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to remove the lyrics, and then insert the changed ones from the text file.  Resync.  Now, the iPad audio is still the old version (several weeks old), but the lyrics are the new version!

At various times during all this, laptop was rebooted, iPad was rebooted, Finder was relaunched, etc.

Comment: It's probably an optimisation technique. I can imagine it going through the list saying to itself, "Yeah, got that one… got that one, got that, got that, don't got that…"

Comment: Seems to me that if this were an "optimization technique" Apple added about a year ago that my question would be tagged "duplicate of ...."

Comment: Maybe no-one else tried editing tunes after they'd already been added...

Comment: Definitely sounds like a cache issue. Are you opening or moving around any of the actually files that are also being synced for no reason? Something could be changing in the meta data causing them to be re-synced again. You should try to take the song that you want edited, copy it to your desktop. Have iTunes remove it from the library as well as trash the original file. Then sync your device. This should remove the file from iOS. Then copy/rename/edit the desktop file and then import it into iTunes again. Then re-sync your device.

Comment: The one that DIDN'T download is fixed more easily than that: uncheck it from the items to be synced, sync to remove from iPad, re-check and re-sync to load the correct version.  None of the unnecessary copies have been moved, edited, or played in iTunes.  Some have been played on the iPad.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Maybe.  But no one else has iTunes recopying dozens of tracks that don't need it?

Comment: Both issues still happening on the latest (Sep 2020) versions.  Reported to Apple as a bug long ago with no evidence they've even read it.  (Their usual response is to ask me to shop them two tons of debug logs which they haven't done on this one.)